# Atom throws spawn EACCES

Tags: atom-editor

I have installed Atom editor then installed Atom Beautify package into it. But when I try to apply beautify package its throws the error below:

```
Error: spawn EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:302:11)
at exports.spawn (child_process.js:379:9)
at /home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:322:13
at Promise._execute (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:284:9)
at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:480:18)
at new Promise (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
at PHPCSFixer.module.exports.Beautifier.spawn (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:319:16)
at /home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:281:10
at tryCatcher (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:509:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:566:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
at Promise._fulfill (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:635:18)
at PromiseArray._resolve (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:125:19)
at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:143:14)
at Promise._settlePromise (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:571:26)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
at Async.drainQueues (/home/titan5/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
```

can anybody help please

Comment: This usually indicates a permission error.

Comment: HI Matt, I know it is but can't identify which file/directory needs the permission

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I put `php-cs-fixer` at `~/.local/bin` and then I gave it executable permission with the command `chmod +x php-cs-fixer`.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this error just now as well. The issue was that I didn't have [Uncrustify](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify) installed.

On Linux:

```
cd ~/
git clone https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify
cd uncrustify
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
sudo make install
```